# How to create LINQ condition with an int Array?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I've got 2 arrays of Int, and I want to keep only elements from second array that contains the first array elements.

```
int [] first = new int[2]  { 1,  2};
int [] second = new int[5]  { 99,  1, 2, 97, 95};
```

I have tried something like below.

```
foreach(int x in first){
second.Where(s=>s==x);
}
```

But it doesn't help me because I need to compare both elements from first array

```
second.Where(s=>s==x[0] && s[1])
```

and if the int is bigger I need. Do you have any ideas how to get below code line?

```
second.Where(s=>s==x[0] && s== x[1] && ... && s==x[n])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elements = second.Where(first.Contains);
```

Maybe materialize it with a `.ToList()` or `ToArray()` call.

If the first list is really large, you could think about a faster version than the `.Contains` method, but for your lists, it would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firstSet = first.ToHashSet();
var result = second.Where(x => firstSet.Contains(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: please add explanation to have a complete answer